# how can i compare a var in class enum with a var in fun main for make a when statements

Tags: kotlin, enums

I am trying make a menu using enum in kotlin, but i don't know how reference for compare the value of getOption in ENUM with var option in main fun. How can i refence getOption in my fun main for compare?

```
fun main() {

     val clienteFundo = fundo()
     val clienteDados = cliente()
     var option: Int = 1;

     when(option){
          option = Menu.SALDO.getOption -> 
          println("test");
     }
}



enum class Menu(val optionName: String, val getOption: Int){
    SALDO("Saldo", 1),
    SACAR("Sacar", 2),
    DEPOSITAR("Depositar", 3),
    EXTRATO("Extrato", 4),
    SAIR("Sair", 5)
}



enum class Menu: GetMenu{
    SALDO{
         override fun getMenu() = 1
     },
    SACAR{
        override fun getMenu() = 2
    },
    DEPOSITAR{
         override fun getMenu() = 3
    },
    EXTRATO{
        override fun getMenu() = 4
    },
    SAIR{
        override fun getMenu() = 5
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```kotlin
fun main() {

     val clienteFundo = fundo()
     val clienteDados = cliente()
     var option: Int = 1;

     when(option){
          Menu.SALDO.getOption -> println("test")
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, solve my problem.

Comment: You can also upvote the answer if you are willing to do so ;)

Comment: I need 15 reputation for do this, but i left a feeedback for when I get to this reputation.